# Does eating manuka honey help prevent acne?

Tags: dermatology, acne, natural-remedy

Does eating manuka honey help prevent acne?

What I have found so far is unsubstantiated or in vitro.

{1}:

> The Internet is filled with patient testimonials that Manuka honey works marvelously for acne and eczema patients. At this time there are no clinical trials to support these claims, but this doesn’t bother me at all.

{2}:

> Manuka honey is
>   renowned for its prolific ameliorative effects on sore throat,
>   burns, infections, gum problem, acne, indigestion; and gastrooesophageal
>   reflux.
>
> [...]
>
> Manuka honey has been proven to be an effective agent in
>   healing diabetic wounds, venous ulcers, burns, acne, eczema,
>   psoriasis.

However they don't provide any reference.

{3}:

> Quinine honey (Cinchona succirubra) from in plantations of quinine (Cinchona succirubra) and it’s in vitro antimicrobial activity against to some acne vulgaris bacteria was evaluated using the CLSI M07-A9 standar method. Quinine honey (Cinchona succirubra) was active against all the species tested, namely Propionibacterium acnes, Staphylococcus epidermidis and Staphylococcus aureus using broth microdilution method. The MIC’s being 32 μg/mL, 128 μg/mL and 128 μg/mL, while MBC for all test bacteria was > 512 μg / mL, respectively. The susceptibility of four honey quinine samples as acne vulgaris compared with commercial anti acne vulgaris erythromycin stearate, tetracycline HCl and two “Manuka” honey which contain the active compound 400+ and 550+ methylglyoxal (MGO) as antimicrobial. **The results strongly suggest that quinine honey can be developed as a natural anti acne vulgaris agent**.

However they focused on quinine honey and the study is in vitro.

---

References:

- {1} https://draxe.com/manuka-honey-benefits-uses/
- {2} Patel, Seema, and Simon Cichello. "Manuka honey: an emerging natural food with medicinal use." Natural products and bioprospecting 3, no. 4 (2013): 121-128. https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=10499495261949890046&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5; https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s13659-013-0018-7.pdf
- {3} Dewi, Mira Andam, Rahmana Emran Kartasasmita, and Marlia Singgih Wibowo. "IN VITRO ANTIMICROBIAL ACTIVITY OF QUININE HONEY (Cinchona succirubra) AS ANTI ACNE VULGARIS." 2nd ISEJ 2017 Abstract and Full Paper Submission System 1, no. 1 (2017): 160-160.  https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=IN+VITRO+ANTIMICROBIAL+ACTIVITY+OF+QUININE+HONEY+%28Cinchona+succirubra%29+AS+ANTI+ACNE+VULGARIS&btnG= ; http://dashboardffup.info/ojs/index.php/ojs_isej2017/article/view/156